# Tic Tac Toe in Python

Tags: python, game, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a mediocre Tic Tac Toe game. Take a look.

```
# Tic-Tac-Toe

# Plays the game of tic-tac-toe against a human opponent

# global constants

X = "X"

O = "O"

EMPTY = " "

TIE = "TIE"

NUM_SQUARES = 9

def display_instruct():
    """Display game instructions."""


    print(

    """
    Welcome to the greatest intellectual challenge of all time: Tic-Tac-Toe.
    This will be a showdown between your human brain and my silicon processor.
    You will make your move known by entering a number, 0 - 8. The number
    will correspond to the board position as illustrated:
    0 | 1 | 2
    ---------
    3 | 4 | 5
    ---------
    6 | 7 | 8

    Prepare yourself, human. The ultimate battle is about to begin. \n
    """
    )
def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Ask a yes or no question."""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):

    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

def pieces():

    """Determine if player or computer goes first."""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Do you require the first move? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nThen take the first move. You will need it.")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
         print("\nYour bravery will be your undoing... I will go first.")
         computer = X
         human = O
    return computer, human

def new_board():

    """Create new game board."""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):

    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8], "\n")

def legal_moves(board):

    """Create list of legal moves."""
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves

def winner(board):

    """Determine the game winner."""
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
    (3, 4, 5),
    (6, 7, 8),
    (0, 3, 6),
    (1, 4, 7),
    (2, 5, 8),
    (0, 4, 8),
    (2, 4, 6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
    if EMPTY not in board:
        return TIE
        return None
def human_move(board, human):

    """Get human move."""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8):", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human. Choose another.\n")
            print("Fine...")
    return move

def computer_move(board, computer, human):

    """Make computer move."""
    # make a copy to work with since function will be changing list
    board = board[:]
    # the best positions to have, in order
    BEST_MOVES = (0, 7, 6, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5, 2)
    print("I shall take square number", end=" ")
    # if computer can win, take that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
    # done checking this move, undo it
    board[move] = EMPTY
    # if human can win, block that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
    # done checking this move, undo it
    board[move] = EMPTY
    # since no one can win on next move, pick best open square
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
        return move

def next_turn(turn):

    """Switch turns."""
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X

def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):

    """Congratulate the winner."""
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print(the_winner, "won!\n")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!\n")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more. \n" \
        "Proof that computers are superior to humans in all regards.")
    elif the_winner == human:
        print("No, no! It cannot be! Somehow you tricked me, human. \n" \
        "But never again! I, the computer, so swear it!")
    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me. \n" \
        "Celebrate today... for this is the best you will ever achieve.")

def main():

    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)
    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)

# start the program

main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to quit.")
```

Comment: You could implement some sort of ai into your program. I managed to win the first game I played. Because the program didn't saw the 'X X' - position.

Comment: There's a Python book called *Python Programming Third Edition: For The Absolute Beginner* by Michael Dawson where this exact code features, although this guy has changed the order for `BEST_MOVES` presumably to make an unbeatable opponent, as one of the 'challenges' the book provides is to do this (I was doing this task myself and became a bit unsure by the challenge). This might be why there is a lot of repetition in the coding, as the book structures its chapters in a different way to the 'most efficient route' possible from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WAYS_TO_WIN` could be a global constant too, like the other variables you named with all caps.

`X` and `O` are not great names. Single-letter variable names are usually not great, and `O` is easy to mistake for 0 (zero). I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
MOVE_X = "X"
MOVE_O = "O"
```

Or, considering that `EMPTY` doesn't explain itself very much either, and all these represent possible tile values in the game:

```
TILE_X = "X"
TILE_O = "O"
TILE_EMPTY = " "
```

---

This is not very efficient:

> ```
> while response not in range(low, high):
>     response = int(input(question))
> ```

It generates a range every time, and if the value is not in the range, it iterates over all items every time. It would be better to check using comparisons with `low` and `high`:

```
while not low <= response < high:
    response = int(input(question))
```

---

`legal_moves` could be written much simpler using a list comprehension:

```
def legal_moves(board):    
    """Create list of legal moves."""
    return [x for x in range(NUM_SQUARES) if board[x] == EMPTY]
```

---

This code checks `not in legal` unnecessarily many times:

> ```
> move = None
> while move not in legal:
>     move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8):", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
>     if move not in legal:
>         print("\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human. Choose another.\n")
>         print("Fine...")
> ```

It could be refactored to avoid wasted operations:

```
while True:
    move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8):", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
    if move not in legal:
        print("\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human. Choose another.\n")
        print("Fine...")
    else:
        break
```

You have several other similar loops with wasted operations that could be refactored similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in programming you should never repeat yourself.

Now look the following two functions that you wrote:

```
def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Ask a yes or no question."""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):

    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response
```

You can easily create one function that does the job of both.

```
def ask(question,choices):
    """Ask a question, keep asking again
    until the user enters a valid choice."""
    response = None
    while response not in choices:
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response
```

---

You are repeating yourself down here too: (too many `print` functions)

```
def display_board(board):

    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8], "\n")
```

You should use triple quoted string and `.format()`

```
def display_board(board):

    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("""
    {0} | {1} | {2}
    ------------
    {3} | {4} | {5}
    ------------
    {6} | {7} | {8} """.format(board[0],board[1],board[2],board[3],board[4],
    board[5],board[6],board[7],board[8]))
```

If you were following, you may have noted that this code still repeats the same thing `board` over and over again. Try and make it less repetitive.

> `"""The board... """.format(*board)`
>  [* unpacks a list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)